# How to fix this Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.getPackageRelationship

Tags: java, pdf, apache-poi

```
public class CreatePdf {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CreatePdf pdf = new CreatePdf();
        System.out.println("start");
        pdf.ConvertToPDF("D:\\doctopdf.docx", "D:\\Test1.pdf");
    }

    public void ConvertToPDF(String docPath, String pdfPath) {

        try {
            InputStream doc = new FileInputStream(new File(docPath));
            XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(doc);
            PdfOptions options = PdfOptions.create();
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(pdfPath));
            PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(document, out, options);
            System.out.print("Done");
      /*}catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
            System.out.print(ex.getMessage());*/
        }catch(IOException ex){
            System.out.print(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }   
}
```

> My requirement is to create a java code to convert existing docx into pdf with proper format and alignment.

Comment: Where do you call that method?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer, apparently this is thrown from the library code

Answer (score 3):

quick google on the title gave me this (still open) issue
https://github.com/opensagres/xdocreport/issues/208

and the very last comment there says

> khausam commented on 12 Mar I was using: compile group:
>   'fr.opensagres.xdocreport', name:
>   'org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.xhtml', version: '1.0.6'
>
> I switched to: compile group: 'fr.opensagres.xdocreport', name:
>   'fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.xhtml', version: '2.0.1'
>
> And the problem was resolved. Can anyone confirm whether this is a
>   reasonable and viable upgrade path?

Comment: I changed the version of poi library from poi 3.17 to poi 3.15. And the problem was resolved.